# Spring Boot and Logback: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, logback

I have recently updated my Spring Boot version from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1 and started to get this error while running my app from IntelliJ:

```
15:26:09.700  INFO [Thread-2] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext     - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2898ac89: startup date [Fri Nov 25 15:26:04 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
15:26:09.701  WARN [Thread-2] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext     - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.removeObject(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.markAsUninitialized(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:265) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.cleanUp(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:196) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onContextClosedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:248) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:989) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>repgen</groupId>
    <artifactId>RepGen</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>RepGen</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <start-class>repgen.Application</start-class>
        <!-- Test -->
        <assertj.version>2.2.0</assertj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!--<version>5.2.2.FINAL</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>log4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.2.16</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!-- JODA-TIME -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- APACHE COMMONS for List Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SAXON XSLT Processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0-8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- APACHE FOP for xsl-fo object formatting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- APACHE POI for office documents -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Databases: Oracle. This needs to be manually imported into local Maven repo. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAVA Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ZIP file related -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

The application works fine, but this exception is thrown at the end of the operation. I have tried to find anything related, but those solutions do not help my case...

Comment: Remove the logback dependency. Spring Boot may use another version.

Comment: @simas_ch I cannot remove it, because I need it :)

Comment: Exactly this version?

Comment: @simas_ch you are correct. Spring version 1.4.1 has a problem with logback versions 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 (these are the ones I have tested). Switching to 1.1.3 removed the error. Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the dependencies as suggested by @DenissM. Spring Boot used Logback y default and already includes a version.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using this specific version of logback because the latest one which is 1.1.7 I think has a bug with <TO> field of SmtpAppender.

Comment: Correct, but that is easily fixed by specifying `<logback.version>1.1.6</logback.version>` in your `<properties>` section of your pom. You don't need to specify / override logback for that. But you have that with other dependencies as well (mail, jUnit etc those are already managed by the different spring-boot-starters you already include). In short you could probably do some cleaning up...

Comment: @M.Deinum That is perfect: IMHO would be the best answer to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with my Spring Boot 1.5.2 application. Upgrading both logback-core and logback-classic to at least version 1.1.3 fixed it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```